# Unable to remove a deleted identity "Service Principle" at root scope "/"

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

I have tried to remove the Service Principle role assignment by running:

az role assignment delete --assignee *** --scope "/" --role "Owner"

but I'm receiving this error:

"Cannot find user or service principal in graph database for ***. If the assignee is an appId, make sure the corresponding service principal is created with 'az ad sp create --id *** "

So then I try to create a SP by giving it the same id and I get:

"The appId *** of the service principal does not reference a valid application object."

Has anyone experienced this before, any assistance would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: check if there is an existing service principal with the appId you're trying to use. should be:  | az ad sp list --filter "appId eq 'APP_ID'"   If you see the service principal in the list, it should reference a valid application object. If it doesn't, you may need to delete the incorrect service principal and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The error usually occurs if you are passing **wrong ID** value for **`--assignee`** parameter while deleting role assignment.

I have one service principal assigned with **Owner** role under subscription scope like this:

[image]

When I tried to delete role assignment by passing **App registration's** Object ID, I too got **same error** as below:

```
az role assignment delete --assignee <appObjID> --scope "/subscriptions/<subID>" --role "Owner"
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, make sure to pass **service principal's** Object ID that can be found in **Enterprise applications** with same application name.

You can also run below CLI command to get **service principal's** Object ID:

```
az ad sp list --filter "displayName eq 'SriSerPrincipal'" --out tsv --query '[].[displayName,id]'
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran same command by passing **service principal's** Object ID, role assignment deleted successfully like below:

```
az role assignment delete --assignee <spObjID> --scope "/subscriptions/<subID>" --role "Owner"
```

[image]